# date picker button image not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a date picker in my application and added a image to the imagebutton. But i am not able to see the image. It is showing cross mark.

Here is my code any help please?

```
  $.datepicker.setDefaults({ showOn: 'button', buttonImage: "~/Content/images/calendar.gif", buttonImageOnly: true });
```

I have the image in the respective path.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in what context are you applying the above line of code? can you show us the rest of it? are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: no i am not getting any error. I am trying to add date control to my page. Onclick of buttonimage i am taking the date for further processing. Button on click working and im getting the selected date. but image not coming

Answer (score 0):

As that image is being referenced from browser. It will not be able to access your desktop. please give the path relative to the current file or with respect to the web root.

Comment: i didnt understand. can you please explain in deatil.

Comment: when u are using "~" i believe u are referring to the desktop which will not be accesible by the browser. Please post the url how are you opening the page in browser so that I can answer more specifically

Comment: C:\Internal Project\SMS\Sms Production Version 2.0\FloorPlanner\Content\images\calendar.gif

Comment: how to give the url, can you please tell me

Comment: can u post the url how you are opening the html page?

Comment: and what is the path to html file in the system?